# Service worker without cache

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
if (e.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
    console.log("matched url")
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request).then(function (response) {
            //return response || fetch(e.request);
            return fetch(e.request);
        })
    );
} else {
    console.log("not matched url")
}
});
```

All I want to do is to serve **only some** of my pages and resources from cache, not everything (I believe it puts cached pages into runtime cache).

This commented piece of code: **return response || fetch(e.request);** serves all pages cached... the website is really dynamic. That's why I just use **return fetch(e.request);** now.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code sample might actually help: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/selective-caching/service-worker.js

Here's also a live demo: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/selective-caching/

The idea, as far as I understand it, is pretty simple: make a map of expected URLs that are supposed to be cached and then check each request for the url:

TLDR;

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  var expectedCacheNames = Object.keys(CURRENT_CACHES).map(function(key) {
    return CURRENT_CACHES[key];
  });

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (expectedCacheNames.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES.font).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }

        return fetch(event.request.clone()).then(function(response) {
          if (response.status < 400) {
            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          }

          return response;
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```